# Plotly Dash: filter DataTable based on plot selection

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Plotty DataTable showing a Pandas DataFrame. The DataFrame has one LineChart for each column in the data frame. Each line chart has one line for each ID represented in the data. I am trying to make it easier to correlate odd looking graphical data to the raw input data.

I want to be able to click on a data point (or better yet select a line in the ChartLegend), doing this would cause the DataTable to filter and only show rows associated with the selected id.

Here is the code snippet for how i produce make the DataTable and Charts

```
def Make_PlottyFigures(df, xcol_name, device_type_dict, device_names, columns_to_plot):
    figs = []
    for col_i in range(0, len(columns_to_plot)):            
        figs.append(go.Figure())

    #Go over each device, and add a trace for each column to the appropriate figure. We want each colun in its own figure 
    for device in device_names:
        if df[df['id'] == device].shape[0] > 0:
            axs_index = 0
            for col in columns_to_plot:
                figs[axs_index].add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[xcol_name], y=df[df['id'] == device][col],
                        mode='lines+markers',
                        name=f"{device_type_dict[device]}-{device}"))
                axs_index += 1

    index = 0;
    for col in columns_to_plot:
        figs[index].update_layout(
        title=f"{col}",
        xaxis_title="",
        yaxis_title="",
        font=dict(
                family="Courier New, monospace",
                size=18,
                color="#7f7f7f"
            )
        )
        index += 1
    return figs


def DASH_dataTable_from_pd(id, df):
    return dash_table.DataTable(
        id=f'datatable-{id}',
        columns=[
            {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": False} for i in df.columns
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=False,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="multi",
        column_selectable="single",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current= 0,
        page_size= 10,
    )
```

I have tried looking online for something similar but havent found anything. https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity has a 'sorta' example but its in the opposite direction( Making selections in the Table highlight the equivilant chart data entry). https://dash-docs.herokuapp.com/interactive-graphing has examples on how to react to the events I am interested in, I am just stuck on how to get the Table filtered off these events firing (also making this releasable would be nice)

Are there any samples that i missed out on or is this dead obvious and i'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to re-set the `data` property of the table, passing only rows you want to display. You can listen to trace click events, determine the clicked trace by index, *customdata* or any other property the *clickData* object comes with.

This basic example illustrates the idea:

```
df = [...]

@app.callback(
    Output("my-table", "data"),
    [Input("my-plot", "clickData")]
)
def on_trace_click(click_data):
    """Listen to click events and update table, passing filtered rows"""
    p = trace_click['points'][0]

    # here, use 'customdata' property of clicked point, 
    # could also use 'curveNumber', 'pointIndex', etc.
    if 'customdata' in p:
        key = p['customdata']['my-key']

    df_f = get_corresponding_rows(df, key)

    return df_f.to_dict('records')

def get_corresponding_rows(df, my_key):
    """Filter df, return rows that match my_key"""
    return df[df['key-column'] == my_key]
```

It's important that your row ids don't change just because of filtering. That way, any styling, *selected* state etc. will still be applied properly.